# Extra space in labels on some pages of a map book resulting in invalid searches

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, labeling, export, pdf

I have exported a map book (Arcmap 10.1). All the labels appear fine but on a particular page - if I search for label for a particular layer - I don't receive any result. I copy and pasted this label on notepad and noticed space being added to these labels e.g. this 9239 exists but Adobe Reader page is generating the error and when I copy this label and print to notepad, it is actually being read as '92 39'.

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include your label expression, and a sample of your data?  Are you sure that the underlying value doesn't have a space?

Comment: Are you exporting your PDF from a map book generated using data driven pages or one of the earlier methods?

Comment: What happens if you export just a zoomed in Data View of that area and keep your map book out of the loop?